# Model redundant django tables?

Tags: python, database, django, database-design, django-models

I am working to figure out the model for a Django project: an app to track `Books`.

Among other fields, every Book has either/both a `Printer` and a `Publisher`, which are basically identical.  So, here's how it stands:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title     = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    printer   = models.ForeignKey('Printer')
    publisher = models.ForeignKey('Publisher')

class Printer(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location  = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

It seems to me this is bad database form: it's not DRY.  In addition, quite often, a `Book` might be printed by a firm which publishes the same or another book: in other words, the tables can overlap.  So, the two models `Printer` and `Publisher` should really be combined, while they need to remain distinct in the admin.

My question: how best to do this?  Should I create another model, `Firm`, and create one-to-one relationships between it and `Printer`/`Publisher`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django way to handle that is to create an `Abstract Base Model`.  This is the DRY way to create your models.  Here is the code:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location  = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Printer(BaseModel):
    pass

class Publisher(BaseModel):
    pass
```

This will allow you to specify redundant fields only once.  Also, if you need to add any extra fields to one model, just add them instead of using `pass`.

Comment: OK, that's a good idea.  I'm not sure, though.  Won't this still create two tables, one for `Publisher` and another for `Printer`? I need a single table for both, I think, so I don't have redundant data.  For example, `Penguin Books` might publish one book and print a second: I don't want a record for `Penguin` in both tables.  Does this make sense?  Maybe I should clarify my question.

Comment: I would create a `BooleanField` then to say `yes/no` if the book is published.

Comment: yikes just realized I hadn't marked this as answered.  Fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: Good! Glad we're both at it still coding a year later!